# Why is the pointwise product of complex-valued continuous functions on a locally compact Hausdorff space continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and let $C(X) = \{ f \colon X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\ \vert\ f \text{ is continuous on } X \}$. How do I show that $fg \colon X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined by $(fg)(x) = f(x)g(x)$ is continuous on $X$?

Answer (score 2):

Because you have maps $f, g: X \rightarrow \Bbb C$, you have a continuous map $(f \times g): X \rightarrow \Bbb C\times \Bbb C$ given by $(f\times g)(x) = (f(x),g(x))$. This is continuous because each of its component functions are.

Then compose with the (continuous!) multiplication map $\Bbb C \times \Bbb C \rightarrow \Bbb C$, $(z_1, z_2) \mapsto z_1z_2$.

The composition of these two maps is $fg$, and as each map was continuous, $fg$ is continuous as desired.

Comment: Why is $(z_1, z_2) \mapsto z_1 z_2$ continuous?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to do the following steps:

1) Show that $h^2$ is continuous for any $h \in C(X)$- this is easy by considering $(h^2)^{-1}(U)$, where $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is open.

2) Show that sums of continuous functions are cont.

3) So, $(f+g)^2$ is cont.

But, then so is $(f+g)^2-f^2-g^2=2fg$

Comment: Why is $(h^2)^{-1}(U)$ open? And why is $(f+g)^{-1}(U)$ open?

Comment: @ooo: write down the definitions of these sets, and you will see.

Comment: $(h^2)^{-1}(U) = \{ x \in X : h(x)^2 \in U \}$ and $(f+g)^{-1}(U) = \{ x \in X : f(x) + g(x) \in U \}$. I still can't see it.